# Real time OS (RTOS) for Raspberry Pi to make a CNC Controller

Tags: raspberry-pi, operating-system, rtos, cnc

this is my first post please be kind.
I have experience programming C++, but it has been a few years since I did anything...

I would like to program a real-time CNC controller, to run CNC machines without a motion controller. I will use a Raspberry Pi and connect it to a MESA card for running all the physical inputs and outputs.

The application and GUI for touch screens will in the future support a small simple slicer for 3D printers, and some simple CAM operations for graphically programming CNC machines for simple tasks.

What RTOS would you recommend to build my program on?

-I have thought about making a Linux based system run realtime, or maybe use Zephyr OS.

Please share your thoughts.

Regards William

Comment: The Raspberry pi, does, by default, not run an RTOS. There might be some that work, but they probably have missing support for all the nice libraries people use. I would recommend using the Pi as kind of high-level-controller, running a default Raspbian and use an external microcontroller (Arduino, or ESP32) for the real-time stuff.

Comment: Hi PMF, it's funny I was just thinking the same thing. I have thought about sending a string with motor position codes to an Arduino, that then translates the information into PWM signals for the steppers. That is the most critical realtime operation that has to take place. it's i good idea, i want to design my own breakout board anyway, so now I'll just make sure to intergrade an Arduino.

Comment: If you need PWM, using an Arduino is anyway a good idea, since the Raspi itself has only 2 PWM channels anyway.